# Property with attribute 'retain (or strong)' was selected for synthesis

Tags: objective-c, xcode

***Property with attribute 'retain (or strong)' was selected for synthesis***

This is a new error that appeared after updating from xcode 9.2 to xcode 9.3. This happens when building my test project, one of my variables is throwing this error:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* myVariable;
```

This has been a 'retain' property for a very long time in this old code base, does anyone have any idea why there is suddenly an error?

Additional information:

There are several of the same name variables throughout the project, all defined the same way in various @protocol files. These protocols are all at some point #import into the test project, which throws the error when it tries to build.

Is there additional information I can provide?

**Edit**

In the process of making this error recreate-able it became apparent that the error is due to one of the duplicate variable names within the project having a 'readonly' property rather than the 'retain' that the rest have. I'm posting the recreation and answer in case anyone else has an old project or typo throwing the same error.

This can be recreated:

- Create a new single view ios project
- Use objective C and include unit tests
- Add a header file that is an @protocol containing the given 'myVariable'
- Add a second @protocol header file matching the first, then change 'retain' to 'readonly'
- Add a new NSObject 
  `@interface MyObject : NSObject <MyProtocol, MyProtocol2>`
- In the implementation of MyObject `@synthesize myVariable;`
- Run unit tests - error should appear

Comment: "Is there additional information I can provide?" Absolutely. Provide enough information for us to see the problem for ourselves. Just make an empty project and see what has to be put into it to make the problem happen. Then tell us how to do that.

Comment: @matt I knew if I had time to recreate I would solve the problem, unfortunately didn't have time last week and was hoping someone else had encountered the same problem. Now have added those steps.

Comment: Since you seem to have answered your own question, you could post your solution as an answer. It's fine to answer your own question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came down to not realizing that one of the variables with the same name was a readonly property while the others were all retain. It seems that xcode 9.2 and previous never caught such an error either but xcode 9.3 now does. My solution was to change the readonly to match the retain variables.

A better solution for others may be to rename the readonly variable to denote it is unique.